# Can python IDLE be used to create a play store app

Tags: text

I have being learning programming during this few months specifically PYTHON AND JAVASCRIPT, but i want to ask if we use python idle for real projects or is just for learning and if only for learning then which code editor is used for creating real apps and software that we see on play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course you can make apps with python. U should use the kivy framework. The kivy framework is a cross-platform framework ,which works on all devices. I recently made app with kivy and python and published to the playstore. It is a universal quiz app.
Here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sivaram.uquiz

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. But the end result is usually that the python code is converted into java code. Your question can be easily googled.

Look into Kivy for example.